# How to implement dragging in Kobold2d using KKInput?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, kobold2d

This must be a rather simple solution that I am simply missing. How do I implement a simple drag and drop using KKInput?

I am trying something like this in the update method.

```
KKInput* input = [KKInput sharedInput];
if ([input touchesAvailable]){
    if ([input isAnyTouchOnNode:[self getChildByTag:0] touchPhase:KKTouchPhaseAny]) {
        [sprite setPosition:[input locationOfAnyTouchInPhase:KKTouchPhaseAny]];
    }
}
```

It works alright, but there are two issues. 1. You can escape the drag by moving really fast and 2. If you drag over the sprite with a tag below, it grabs that one.

What am I missing?

Comment: touch began on sprite: set drag flag, remember sprite. move event= update sprite pos to touch pos. touch ended: clear drag flag.

Comment: My apologies, could you explain the process to set a drag flag? Still lost here. Thank you for answering Steffen.

Answer (score 0):

After some help from LearnCocos2D here is what I did.

First I created a BOOL called isDragging and set it to no in init. I also created a property to keep track of what sprite is being touched.

```
if ([input touchesAvailable] && isDragging == NO){
    if ([input isAnyTouchOnNode:[self getChildByTag:0] touchPhase:KKTouchPhaseAny]) {
        draggedSprite = zero; // Grab this pointer for use next
        isDragging = YES; 
    }
}
```

Then I set dragging to NO is no touches are available.

```
if (![input touchesAvailable]) {
    isDragging = NO;
}
```

Then simply update the current sprite being dragged to the touch location.

```
if (isDragging){
    draggedSprite.position = [input locationOfAnyTouchInPhase:KKTouchPhaseAny];
}
```